# How to use multiple LIKE with AND conditions in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Hi I am trying to group by on values that satisfies my criteria

I want to select the client that has only dove.p1 and  dove.p2 products

I tried the following methods  and none worked:

```
SELECT
    sh.clients as clients,
    sh.products  AS products
FROM shopping sh
WHERE products LIKE  'dove.p1%' AND products LIKE 'dove.p2%'
GROUP BY 1


SELECT
    sh.clients as clients,
    sh.products  AS products
FROM shopping sh
WHERE products  SIMILAR TO   'dove.p1%|dove.p2%'
GROUP BY 1


    SELECT
    sh.clients as clients,
    sh.products  AS products
FROM shopping sh
WHERE products  LIKE ALL (array_agg['dove.p1%','dove.p2%'])
GROUP BY 1
```

None of them really solved this issue, can someone show me the right method to deal with this?

| Clients | Products |
| --- | --- |
| brad | [dove.p2.shampoo, dove.p1.deodorant, os.p3.deodorant] |
| chad | [dove.p1.shampoo, dove.p1.deodorant, nv.p3.deodorant] |

Comment: Make use of  brackets   `  NOT ((p AND q) OR (NOT p AND r))
  = NOT (p AND q) AND NOT (NOT p AND r)
  = (NOT p OR NOT q) AND (p OR NOT r) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed in comments, you must use brackets or at least OR. I'm not sure if you need an array in output.

If yes you can use:

```
SELECT
    sh.clients as clients,
    ARRAY_AGG (sh.products) AS products
FROM shopping sh
WHERE products LIKE  'dove.p1%' OR products LIKE 'dove.p2%'
GROUP BY clients
```

If you want a string use:

```
SELECT
    sh.clients as clients,
     string_agg(sh.products, ',')  AS products
FROM shopping sh
WHERE products LIKE  'dove.p1%' OR products LIKE 'dove.p2%'
GROUP BY clients
```